# Counting from many-to-many

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I check if a tag is at least used once based on the structure below.

[image: Table structure]

Comment: Generally, plain text is preferred over images. One cannot copy text from an image. Also, it is *always* a good idea to mention version numbers. Newer versions provide new features ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join is most probably the fastest of several possible query styles for this task:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM   taggit_tag t
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   taggit_taggeditem ti
   WHERE  ti.tag_id = t.tag_id
   );
```